# api platfrom many to many relationship is not working

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I'm using api-platform in my symfony project
I have many to many relation between entity companyUser and a surveyReceiver entity. I have a join table and I want to add a record to it while updating a companyUser. in fact I want to add a existing surveyReceiver to companyUser object. but instead of adding an existing one it tries to create a new one and then add it to the companyUser object
there is an example below

companyUser entity:

```
#[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: SurveyReceiver::class, inversedBy: "members",cascade: ['persist'])]
#[ORM\JoinTable(name: "membership")]
#[ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'company_user_id',referencedColumnName: "id")]
#[ORM\InverseJoinColumn(name: "survey_receiver_id",referencedColumnName: "id")]
private $surveyReceivers
```

SurveyReceiver entity:

```
#[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: CompanyUser::class, mappedBy: "surveyReceivers")]
private $members;
```

this is my put request.
PUT:company-users/890

```
{
  "name": "xxx,
  "surveyReceivers":[
   {
     "survey_receiver_id" : 6  
   }
  ]
}
```

it will create a record in join table with company_user_id :

| company_user_id | survey_receiver_id |
| --- | --- |
| 890 | 349 |

which is wrong. **survey_receiver_id** should be **6** as it was in request

I would be grateful it you help me to see where I did a mistake or miss sth.

Answer (score 0):

Try it using `PATCH` method instead of `PUT` with `Content-Type` header set to `application/merge-patch+json`